# Error thrown with nnet::multinom() passing programmed as.formula() to emmeans::emmeans()?

Tags: r, nnet, emmeans

One can get the data referenced below from: https://gist.github.com/markhwhiteii/6ce74461a789ddc6d04044de73d99939

I can pass an interaction for a multinomial logistic model to get post hoc tests by hard-coding things:

```
library(nnet)
library(emmeans)
model <- multinom(outcome ~ cond * party, data)
emmeans(model, ~ outcome + cond | party)
```

However, I need to have a wrapper function for this. If I have inputs that are the variables, then pass these `as.formula()`, then I get an error thrown at me:

```
iv <- "cond"
dv <- "outcome"
mod <- "party"
formula <- as.formula(paste(dv, "~", iv, "*", mod))
model <- multinom(formula, data)
emmeans(model, as.formula(paste("~", dv, "+", iv, "|", mod)))
```

The call to `emmeans` generates:

```
Error in object$call$formula[[2]] : 
  object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

It seems like it is coming from the `multinom` function, as I can get the pasted formula in `emmeans` to run with the hard-coded `multinom` model. It is strange, because I have gotten this method to work with `lm`, `glm`, and `clm` models. I looked at the structure of the two `model` objects, and they seem to be identical. Importantly, `model$terms` for both is identical. `emmeans` calls a function which calls a function which calls a method, etc., so it is difficult to figure out where the error is happening using the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a hack to get around this. `multinom` was storing the object name `formula`, not the formula itself, into the `call` attribute of the model:

```
iv <- "cond"
dv <- "outcome"
mod <- "party"
formula <- as.formula(paste(dv, "~", iv, "*", mod))
model <- multinom(formula, data)
model$call$formula
```

Which returns the character `formula`.

I can then re-create the error with:

```
> model$call$formula[[2]]
Error in model$call$formula[[2]] : 
  object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

So, I just manually wrote-over what `multinom` stored:

```
iv <- "cond"
dv <- "outcome"
mod <- "party"
formula <- as.formula(paste(dv, "~", iv, "*", mod))
model <- multinom(formula, data)
model$call$formula <- formula
emmeans(model, as.formula(paste("~", dv, "+", iv, "|", mod)))
```

And it works.